# Link to folders vs Link and create virtual folder in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse IDE, when I drag and drop a folder/file into Project Explorer:

What is the difference between option 2 and 3?

("**Link to files and folders**" vs "**Link to files and recreate folder structure with virtual folder**")

[image: Eclipse link to folder]

Answer (score 2):

In my short experience, the linked folder behaves like a *NIX symbolic link in that files added to the folder in the file system are picked up in the eclipse project simply by refreshing the project, whereas a virtual folder contains only the files in the folder when the virtual folder is created; files added to the file system later are only seen when explicitly added to the eclipse virtual folder.

Answer (score 2):

Normal Files and Normal Folders operate in a way. Linked Files and Folders operate in a different way.

Virtual Files are *not* normal files and Virtual Folders are something different entirely, so each requires special explanation.

A normal folder looks like this:

[image: Normal folder]

When you refresh a directory that is a normal folder, Eclipse will attempt to update that directory in your chosen "Manager" (i.e. Package Manager or Project Manager), including file names, file directory names, and directory contents. You can refresh by highlighting that specific item in the Manager and selecting the context menu item "Refresh".

Files and folders on your hard disk automatically appear inside, if an exclusion rule was not set up.

Getting rid of normal folders, deletes the folder on the file system. Watch out!

A linked folder looks like this:

[image: Linked folder]

When you refresh a directory that is a linked folder, Eclipse will attempt to update that directory in your chosen "Manager".

Getting rid of linked folders, does not delete the content of the folder on the file system.

Getting rid of linked files in those folders does delete the file on the file system. Watch out!

A virtual folder looks like this:

[image: Virtual folder]

A virtual folder is set up relative to the project location, workspace location, or the "eclipse parent". You can only store "virtual files" or "virtual folders" as content in virtual folders. 
A virtual folder will *never* update any of its named contents upon Eclipse refresh. So filenames of virtual files also do not update upon Eclipse refresh.

Getting rid of virtual files or virtual folders, does not delete the file or folder from the file system.

You can use a virtual folder when you want warnings to appear in your chosen manager for not following the structure the virtual folder demands. A red X will appear over the file only in a virtual folder situation. Quite useful if you're keeping up a policy on where files need to be on the file system for your program to run.